# configure secondary hard drive in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: external-hdd

Hi I have installed Ubuntu on ssd and connected my 500 gb hdd with caddy to my laptop.Now when i boot up then sometime my hdd is showing in "other location" option and some time i am not able to access that. SO how can i mount this secondary hdd to /home directory in ubuntu 22.04 so that it cab be accessed easily.

Comment: Is your HHD a IDE or SATA?

Comment: sata hdd which use to come in older laptops

Comment: no IDE is what used to come in old laptops. Then only the SATA drives came into existence. try `sudo mkdir -p ~/HDD && sudo mount <DEVICE_ID> ~/HDD` where <DEVICE ID is the drive in `/dev`